# How far does fair-use apply for a source that contains several critiqued resources?

Tags: copyright, european-union

As far as I'm aware, if you're writing an article on a movie (or something similar), you can use screenshots and such from the movie to illustrate your points under *fair use* law.

**Example:** Under fair use, A blog article about StarWars's dvd artwork would allow the use of images of the covers in the piece.

**Scenario:** This article was one of many on StarWarsDVDs.com - Would *fair use* allow for use of the artwork as the banner for the website? seeing as the site is solely dedicated to the topic.

From what I know of fair use, it's somewhat fuzzily defined - but I was wondering about how it would apply to collections of items that reference the media.

Is using media in this way allowed by fair use?

There might be some instances of this occurring previously, like a published book of movie reviews?

Comment: Seems slightly over broad, too opinion-based, and slightly ambiguous to me?

Comment: @L235 would it help if I edited it down to a single scenario?

Comment: In what country?

Comment: added a europe tag

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Yes, it'd help greatly if you made it clear what question you want answered. Also, this strays into the area of legal advice, which makes me a bit uncomfortable..

Comment: @L235 hopefully this latest edit helps. For what it's worth, I think it fits into the hypotethical application of law like http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/34/are-hypothetical-application-of-the-law-questions-on-topic -